# Bootstrap Modal in MVC 5 Razor: How do I update model boolean value to false when user clicks continue button in modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I want to try to implement this with Ajax post request, but I've never used Ajax and I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

---

My view code for password panel look's like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Reset Password</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" id="myForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("EditPassword", "Users", new { UserId = Model.User.Id, Token = Model.Token }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary()
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div id="dialog-modal" style="display:none;" title="Basic modal dialog"></div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <button type="submit" data-toggle="modal"  data-target=".bootstrapmodal"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Reset" onclick="javascript: return checkPassForm(document.getElementById('myForm'));">Reset</button>
                </div>

            }
        </div>
```

Bootstrap Modal code:

```
    <div class="modal fade bootstrapmodal" id="modalMain" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false" data-keyboard="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button data-dissmiss="modal" class="close modal-close-btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> <span>&times;</span> </button>
                <div class="modal-title"><h3>News Letter Account</h3></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>This is a newsletter only account which does not have an existing password.</p>
                <p>Do you wish to create a mySewnet account for this user?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-updateNL"> Continue </button>
                <button class="btn btn-default cancel-modal" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script code in the same view looks as follows

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btn-updateNL").on('click', function (e) {
           @this.Model.User.NewsletterOnly.Equals(false);
        });

});
```

The controller code for View's reset password panel:

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditPassword(int userId, string token)
    {
        User user = new User();
        EditUserViewModel top = new EditUserViewModel();

        int rer = top.UserId;
        userId = user.Id;
        token = UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetToken(user.Id);


        var model = new EditUserViewModel()
        {

            UserId = userId,
            Token = token
        };

        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { userId = userId });

    }

    //POST: /Admin/UserManager/Edit
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> EditPassword(EditUserViewModel model)
    {

        model.Token = UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetToken(model.UserId);


        var user = this.UserManager.FindById(model.UserId); //Gets current user

        var oldTermsAndConditionAgreement = user.TermsAndConditionsAgreement; //Gets current value of TermsAndConditionsAgreement

        user.TermsAndConditionsAgreement = true; //Sets TermsAndConditionsAgreement to true


        //Run a break on this line next time when coding
        var result = this.UserManager.ResetPassword(model.UserId, model.Token, model.Password.Trim()); //If TermsAndConditionsAgreement is not true, this seems to break

        user.TermsAndConditionsAgreement = oldTermsAndConditionAgreement; //TermsAndConditionsAgreement is set back to original value after process runs

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            TempData["Message"] = AppResources.Common.FormAdminPasswordresetSuccess;
            //return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");

            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

            //return RedirectToAction("Edit");

        }

        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = model.UserId });
    }
```

I want to give 'Reset' button on the password panel the ability to display model panel if user has "newsletteronly" check-box set to "true".Which I can do by placing this Razor if statement syntax around modal code above.

*when Newsletteronly is set to true and checked account is not really a account so admin can't reset user's password, because no password is created in database for users who choose to receive news-letter. Other data like email, name, street address are collected and stored in DB. Email is username in this web-application.

@if (this.Model.User.NewsletterOnly == true)
{}

Doing this only allows the modal to display when reset button is clicked and if user's account meet the condition. The issue I'm having now is in trying to get
model to update for "NewsletterOnly" value to false when 'Continue' button is clicked on modal dialog after page-loads and modal disappears. I believe Ajax post can resolve this but don't know how to implement this with bootsrap modal on MVC 5 Razor .Net.

Images:

[("Page View") description:Left side of view is "user panel" it displays 'NewsletterOnly' checkbox and it is checked as True if user has a news letter only account) Right side displays reset password panel and other panels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdKRX.png)

[Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26u95.png)

Comment: is the problem doing a ajax post?

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure how to go about doing it with Ajax Post. If you know of any good material/tutorial with demo that can teach me this that would be great. but for now I'll try to use javascript/jquery to handle this.

Comment: In regards to NL Newletter value it's actually a boolean value in the database and not string. In my controller action method C# code I defined it as a bool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $("#btn-updateNL").on('click', function (e) {
           $.post("yourActionMethodToUpdateNewsLetterValue",{userId:1,NL:false},function(){
                  alert('updated succesully');
           });
      });
```

where `{userId:1,NL:false}` here you need to pass the current users Id and then pass the value for NewsLetterOnly variable ie: NL as false. You can have a controller method which accepts these two parameters and then write your logic to update the Db.

Controller Action method would be something like

```
 public async UpdateUserNewsLetterFlag(int userId,bool NL)
```

Comment: I've figured it out. Going to post code fix once I'm done testing thanks a lot Reddy.